# How to store device token in Firestore without user id?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to store device tokens in Firestore, to use Firebase Functions to send push notifications to my iOS and Android users.

I read the best practice is to use Firebase user id Auth.auth().currentUser.uid:

users

- {uid}

  - {token}

But my app hasn't user authentification. So I haven't {uid} to use.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging has no knowledge of users, which is why it is a common question how to associate FCM tokens with users.

If you don't want to associate the tokens with specific users, you can just store a collection of tokens:

```
tokens
  {token}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Frank mentioned FCM doesn't know about the users, you can check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) and how works the structure they [use](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications):

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    }
  }
}
```

Therefore, the option is create a collection of tokens.